# Traveling to Canada in less than a month and have slight water damage on my passport

Tags: passports, canada

My boyfriend and I are travelling to Canada on an IEC visa next month and we got caught in the rain the other day. His passport has slight water damage (it’s barely noticeable - the passport is wrinkled, but no ink dissolved, just a slight water mark going across the top of the signature page), we don’t have time for him to get a new one. How strict are Canada with that? Would He be admitted in, or is it a lost cause?

Comment: What is the nature of the damage?  Was any ink dissolved?  Is it nothing more than a bit of wrinkling?  Is the interior affected or only the cover?  It's impossible to say without knowing.

Comment: It got wet in the rain. The passport is wrinkled abut but no ink dissolved just a slight water mark going across the top of the signature page

Comment: I have edited your comment into your question. (Wishing you all the best with your circumstances!) :)

Comment: Thank you, I should of mentioned it in there

Answer (score 2):

If everything on the passport is clearly readable then you will probably be OK. If any part is unreadable then you should get a new one. Most countries allow you to do a passport renewal in well under a month.

If you have time to get a new passport I would still recommend getting a new one, even if everything is readable. The likelihood is that it will be accepted. Much worse things happen to passports on long trips, and I used a water-damaged passport for several year. However the downside of getting an exceptionally strict immigration officer and being refused entry is much more serious than the cost of a new passport.

Comment: Everything is still readable no ink has been smudge or anything. It’s on the signature page but the other side of the sign

Comment: @Jordz123 We're guessing here based on your description. A picture of the passport (with personal details obscured) would be useful.

Comment: My passport has been in the rain a LOT (biking across northern Spain in April).  No one has ever even mentioned the wrinkles at entry and exit controls of twenty countries.

Comment: Does it have any water marks ? Have you ever travel to Canada with it?

Comment: Long ago I was given a hard time and delayed when traveling from England to Belgium, but eventually admitted, with a clearly readable but water-damaged passport (the border control officers thought it might be a forgery). In my case there *might* have been some runny ink (I don't remember).  Replace it if you can.